# Is any grammar edit to the title really too trivial for EL&U?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing, titles

I agree with the policy on trivial edits, but is a title edit for grammar too trivial for EL&U?  Hypothetically - should the web site host questions with grammar that might be construed as incorrect/awkward grammatical structure/colloquial phrase/etc or can there be a waiver to allow short trivial edits on the titles?

For example, the ultimate in triviality: adding a question mark at the end of a question.

Answer (score 7):

As you've had only one edit suggestion rejected, it's not difficult to find the question referred to and the [details](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/34063) of the rejected edit.

Your proposed amendment was to change:

> Is there a word for someone who really has **their** act together

to

> Is there a word for someone who really has **his/her** act together **?**

You will see that it was rejected independently by two separate reviewers. Although I have not seen the edit previously, I would agree with their decision, which gives the standard wording:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

The use of *their* for *his/her* in the question is neither "incorrect" nor "controversial". The discussion of that issue in numerous previous questions on the site show that the usage is long-established, frequently used, understood and accepted.
<sub>[Disclaimer: That statement is made from memory: I have not checked previous questions at this time.]</sub>

My *personal* view is that short edits on question titles should be made where necessary for clarity, but, in this particular case, the suggested edit was both unnecessary and trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm perfectly ok with my "his/her" being rejected on grammatical grounds.  Perhaps the addition of a question mark, albeit trivial, would have been appropriate.

Comment: @JackRyan I agree that the question mark would have been desirable, but, as you say, that would have been trivial! :-)